# Android - setting the "android:layout_column="1"" programatically?

Tags: java, android, layoutparams

How can I set the `android:layout_column="1"` programatically? I've seen some other answers but all of them are something that doesn't really work with my code. All of them say to do something like this:

`layout.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(columnNum))` which isn't really what I want, because I have a GridLayout and I already have a set LayoutParams.

My LayoutParams go like this:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams middleLayoutLayoutParams = (GridLayout.LayoutParams)middleLayout.getLayoutParams();
middleLayoutLayoutParams.columnSpec = col2;
middleLayout.setLayoutParams(middleLayoutLayoutParams);
numBoxes++;
```

But I want something like:
`middleLayout.column = GridLayout.spec(1)`?

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume I have a TextView textViewName in the grid. Now I place it in row 1, column 1 with a column span of 4.

```
    lpGl = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    lpGl.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lpGl.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lpGl.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, 4);
    lpGl.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(1);
    textViewName.setLayoutParams(lpGl);
```

Would this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for replying on four of my questions! I haven't tried it just yet but I will and I'll let you know how it goes.